# Plotting a heatmap in Python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am a new Python user and need help with plotting a heatmap in Python using matplotlib

I have three vectors [x, y, z], each having 7700 elements. I got the code for plotting the heatmap from google search (see below), but ended up with an error

Some pointers

In array "x", all the items are different

In array "y", not all the values are different

In array "z", not all the values are different

```
x = mdf_merged.get('Signal_x').samples  # define the x array
y = mdf_merged.get('Signal_y').samples  # define the y array
z = mdf_merged.get('Signal_z').samples  # define the z array

x=np.unique(x)
x = np.unique(x)
y1, yind = np.unique(y, return_index=True)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y[sorted(yind)])
Z=z.reshape(len(y1),len(x), order='F')
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("X-values")
plt.ylabel("Y-values")
```

I end up with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 7700 into shape (6447,7700)
```

So my questions are

a) What could be the cause and possible solution to this ?

b) Why can't it directly take x, y, and z. Why do I have to do meshgrip and reshape ?

I am a newbie to Python so it could be nice with a little more detailed reply

Comment: At which line in the code you provided does your script fail? It states in your error message that it is line 1, but is it also line 1 in the code shown here?

Comment: I think the error occures in the ```Z=z.reshape(len(y1),len(x), order='F')``` . I'm not sure what this code should to do, so can't say how to fix the issue.

Comment: @Solvalou : The code fails at -> Z=z.reshape(len(y1),len(x), order='F')

Comment: @Tobbor: The code is supposed to plot heatmap. Could there be any other way to do the heat maps, based on my problem statement ?

Comment: If all items are different in x, you will have problems getting a 2D heatmap, because your data only makes up for a 1D line. Can you rethink how exactly you imagine your data to be shown as heatmap?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : To be more precise my data in x is engine speed, y is boost pressure, and z is Turbine temperatures. I would now like to plot Turbine temperatures as a function of (engine speed(x), and boost pressure (y))

In my case x and y are unique operating points for a combustion engine, and z is some output that varies depending on x, y

Comment: plot `plt.scatter(x,y, c=z)`. How will this look? (Maybe put the resulting picture into the question so people have an idea about the nature of your data.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Lets say I have three vectors
x= [1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000]
y= [10 20 30 40 50 60 70]
z= [800 600 700 100 1000 400 600]

I know that scatter plot would help me in cases where a unique z exists for (x, y). But in my case there could be multiple "z" observations for the same x, y. Hence a heatmap would better represent the distribution in such a case

Answer (score 0):

So, with the help from the community, I have been able to reach closer to the solution. The thing that I did was

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = mdf_merged.get('VariableX').samples
y = mdf_merged.get('VariableY').samples
z = mdf_merged.get('VariableZ').samples
###
xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),10)
yi = np.linspace(min(y),max(y),20)
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear')
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi)
```